# Can't import a Git project in Aptana Studio 3

Tags: git, github, aptana

I'm trying to import a project from a Git repository. So, I use the "Import project" wizard and give the URI of the git project of my friend:  git://github.com/username/projectname.git
It gives me this message: "fatal: I don't handle protocol git"

I watch the repository on github but the project is empty for now. Is there any chance that's the problem?

Answer (score 3):

You can't use GitHub by default with Aptana's built-in Git integration.   You have to use EGit (for Eclipse, but since Aptana is an Eclipse derivative, it installs fine), and then do it that way.

In order to install EGit, you'll need to go to Help->Install New Software, and add the following update site to install EGit:

http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates/

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 3):

from my experience with egit, it's really a horrible plugin. The terms they use and the way the interface manage multiple remotes is just confusing.

Try a 3rd party git application, like Tower or SmartGit. You will find these tools much better and simple to use.